# angularjs there is an error in ng options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, select, ng-options

i'm developing an app that should receive a JSON array from the server (localhost in this moment) and populated two selects that made of a form.

The sctructure of the array is this:

```
[{
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "09:45"
  }, {
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "16:50"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "11:25"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "12:30"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "16:10"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "17:25"
  }]
```

And in the first select i should have the days while in the second select i should have the times "belonging" at the day choice in the first select, so for this example i should have this result:

**SELECT 1**:
17/11/2016, 18/11/2016, 21/11/2016

**SELECT 2**:
09:45, 16:50 **OR** 11:25, 13:30 **OR** 16:10, 17:25

This is my code,

**SCRIPT.JS**:

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);

DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService', '$http'];

function DefaultController(dataService, $http) {
  var vm = this;

  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.data = data;
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
    vm.submit = function (){
        console.log("funzione");
        console.log(vm.form);
        var data = vm.form; // IMPORTANT
        //console.clear();
        var link = 'http://localhost//api/apiDoFix.php';
        var mail = window.localStorage.getItem("mail");
        var scelta = window.localStorage.getItem("scelta");
        $http.post(link, {giorno: data.giorno, ora: data.ora, mail: mail, scelta: scelta})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                var response = res.data;
                if (response != 'F'){
                    console.log("Dentro if");
                    window.location.href ="/main.html";
                } else {
                    console.log("Dentro else");
                }
            });
    };
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        var result = {
          events: [],
          schedules: []
        };
        var events = JSON.parse(data);
        var dates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
            var date = events[i].day;
            dates.push(date);
            result.events.push({
              date: date
            });
          }

          result.schedules.push({
            date: events[i].day,
            time: events[i].time
          });
        }

        return result;
      }
    };

    return $http.get('http://localhost/api/apiTimes.php', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);

    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
      return response.data;
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**FORM.HTML**:

```
<div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Giorno:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="idx as event.date for (idx, event) in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un giorno </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Ora:
                            </div>
                            <select ng-options="idx as schedule.time for (idx, schedule) in ctrl.data.schedules| filter: { date: ctrl.form.giorno.date}" ng-model="ctrl.form.ora" ng-disabled="!ctrl.form.giorno">
                                <option disabled>Seleziona un orario </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

This code works but only for a part because the second selects print all the same data, ie the options "belonging" at the first day(the first is correct) are repeated in the other two selects options.

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: Have you tried ng-options="schedule.time as schedule.time" in the select?

Comment: sorry, the code that i've posted works, now post the code that give me this error @user2085143

Comment: i've edited the code @user2085143

Comment: Use a ngChange directive on the first select. When the change event fires you can then populate an array in controller with the times for the selected date. Use this array as the source for the second select